# Dominant term in time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

If an algorithm has time complexity `O(n+m)`, and we know that `m >= n` (e.g., we're traversing a connected graph with `n` nodes and `m` edges). Then I think the following is true:

- `O(n+m) = O(m)`
- `O(n log n + m)` cannot by simplified

Is this correct?

Comment: But it is more accurate, to use O(n+m) to get used to think about properties, that makes the complexity. In general graph m > n, but there are special cases like trees, where m = n-1 or mazes, where typically m = 4*n (you can move in 4 directions: up, down, left, right). This is important for example in contest programming, where program running in O(n + m) can be a lot easier to implement than for example O(n^2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To eliminate one of those terms you'd have to know more about n / m.